# Meta data is visible on site

Tags: css, metadata, meta

I have just tried to add some `<meta>` data to my site within the `<meta>` tag, however it is for some reason visible on the web page.

Can I hide it with CSS?

```
<head>
    <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
    <meta>Lorem Ipsum is a Lorem Ipsum. Bla Bla.</meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: where did you add them? they're suppose to be inside the `<head>` tag

Comment: This doesn't even make sense.  Post your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `meta` tag incorrectly. If you are trying to add a meta description, you would use:

```
<meta name="description" content="Lorem ispum...">
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, the general concept is that meta tags need a `name` and a `content` attribute to work. Also this list will help (it does take a few seconds to load though): http://code.lancepollard.com/complete-list-of-html-meta-tags/